# Function to remove trailing punctuation from string in python

Tags: python, strip, punctuation

My function is:
 `def remove_punctuation(string, punctuation)` and I need to remove all leading and trailing punctuation as specified by punctuation. However, I also need to keep all punctuation that is in a word eg. `"th,is, wo.rd!"` becomes `"th,is wo.rd"` for  `def remove_punctuation("th,is, wo.rd!", "!.,")`. I then need to return the function as a string.

I am trying to self learn python as my lecturer hasn't been all that helpful in teaching us and I have gotten stuck on this problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If your lecturer isn't teaching you python, then ... what are they doing?

Comment: He teaches us the very basics and the questions thrown at us in the practise questions are miles harder than his lectures.

Comment: Have you made any attempts of your own that you would like to share with us?

Comment: `def remove_punc(sentence, punctuation):
    for char in sentence:
        if char in punctuation:
            sentence = sentence.strip(char)
    return sentence`